# Magento Products not visible after migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I have migrated site magento 1.9.3 to magento 2.2.5 using data migration loader, everything is successfully migrated, I can see order, customer and product data on backend but products are not visible on frontend

I have done everything like cache clear, indexing from CLI. Products have proper stock and quantity and are set to enable.

Any leads?

I have these in store configurations
[image]
but in content -> design there are 4 entries
[image]

Comment: Can you check if products are properly assigned with categories as well?

Comment: Is your website multiple store or language? Check correct website id is associated with products

Comment: there is something wrong, edited description

Comment: Check the root category of your stores group